# what is correct?

Tags: prepositions

> The people eat food on the table.

or

> The people eat the food that's on the table.

or

> The people eat food at the table.

The first sentence tells me people sit on the table to eat food.

The second one tells me that the people eat the food that is on the table.

The third one tells me the people sit at the table to eat food.

i was told that the first one is correct. i taught english for 10 years and one of my home stay students came home with homework. i explained that ...people eat the food on the table states people sit on thd table to eat the food.

the 2nd sentence states that the food on thd table is eaten by people.
the last one stayes that people sit at the table to eat the food.
the student csme home telling me that i am wrong about this. i said using 'that is' in the sentence changes the context from people on the table to food on the table. the last one is correct because people sit around the table on chsirs and they eat the food that is on the table.

can others tell me their thoughts as i am a native english speaker and i do not think the first sentence is fully correct the way it is written.

Comment: i [sic] am a little surprised that someone who taught english [sic] for ten years is so careless with capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

All the sentences are "correct" in that they are grammatical and make sense.

You have correctly explained the meaning of each sentence. The first one is only "wrong" in the sense that it describes a rather bizarre way for people to behave.

However, in you description you have changed the sentence to:

> I explained that ... *people eat **the** food on the table* states people sit on thd table to eat the food.

The addition of the definite article changes the meaning of the sentence to mean that the food is only the table and people eat it. Presumably the "correct" meaning. (It is still ambiguous, as it could be interpreted to mean that the people are on the table eating the food. But most people will reject that analysis in favour of the more natural meaning.)

I will leave someone else to explain why adding **the** changes the meaning...

Answer (score 1):

> *The people eat food on the table*.

I'd argue that the first sentence is ambiguous, and can be parsed in more than one way:

> **[The people] [eat food] [on the table]**
>   (The people eat food while they sit or stand on a table)
>
> **[The people eat] [food on the table]**
>   (The people eat food that is on the table)

This sentence may be ambiguous, simple, and ripe for improvement, but I wouldn't go so far as to say it's wrong, ungrammatical, or "not fully correct."

Answer (score -3):

The first sentence is most probably wrong. 
According to the rule, if the phrase "on the table" is used as an adjective for food, it is essential, and so it needs commas. If it doesn't have commas, it either is used as an adverb to "eat", or it is used incorrectly.

Comment: What "rule" is that, please?